# How to recover data from an erased android SD Card

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

Last week when my phone(Galaxy Note 10+) was stolen, I logged into my Google account from my laptop and chose the option to erase the device. The cops managed to catch the guy and retrieve my phone but by that time I had lost all the important stuff on my phone and my SD card. I tried to recover the data from my card by connecting it to my laptop (Windows 10) and using software like EaseUS, Recuva but both didn't find anything to recover. I don't care about anything but family pictures on my phone/SD card which were not synced to any cloud. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with some suggestions on how to recover the erased SD card. I am also new to this forum so please forgive me if I am not following the best guidelines for asking a question and please let me know if there is any other information I should add

Comment: Don't you think an "erase data function" would be worthless if you could easily recover the data later? Phones are a bad place for storing important data you have no backup of as phones can get lost, stolen or destroyed. So always ensure you have the data copied to a safe place.

Comment: I understand and I wish I had them synced to secure cloud account but unfortunately I didn't and those pictures are fond memories with my family so I am trying really hard to get those back and I am hoping someone or some answer from the forum would be able to help me out.

Comment: was the sd card [encrypted](https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/assets/au/support/mobile-devices/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-sd-card/16.jpg)?

Comment: @alecxs No, I had never selected that option

Comment: https://www.klennet.com

Comment: @alecxs That couldn't find any erased files either :(